# Histogram of the frequency of an occurrence in Plotly with Python

Tags: python, plotly, histogram

I would like to create a histogram with the y values representing the number of occurrences of a set and the x axis representing the number of sets. For example...

- Passengers on a ship...
- Age 0-20:  14
- Age 21-40: 27
- Age 41-60: 19

Ideally, there would be three bars (bins) associated with each set. Here is the code I've come up with...

```
# Bins (x-axis)
bins = [1,2,3]

# Trace (y-axis)
passengers = [14, 27, 19]

# Data
data = [go.Histogram(x=bins, y=passengers)]

# Layout
layout = Layout(title='Histogram Example')      
    
# Figure
fig = {'data': data, 'layout': layout}

#Plot
iplot(fig)
```

What is the simplest way to represent this data with Plotly's go.Histogram function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a graph using your data using the official reference. See [here](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

bins = ["Age0-20","Age21-40","Age41-60"]
passengers = ["14","27","19"]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(histfunc="sum", y=passengers, x=bins, name="sum"))

fig.update_layout(showlegend=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Solved the problem. Is there a reason add_trace is used as opposed to defining data or a trace earlier?

Comment: I was just following the official reference, but I think this description is the norm these days.